# Record sound when speaking to mic

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I want to write controller which handles sound recording. It should record sound when there is sound in mic.

I have working code on recording sound when button is pressed.

```
-(IBAction) startRecording
{
    NSLog(@"startRecording");
    audioRecorder = nil;

    // Init audio with record capability
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];

    NSMutableDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:10];
   // if(recordEncoding == ENC_PCM)
    //{

        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatLinearPCM] forKey: AVFormatIDKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:500.0] forKey: AVSampleRateKey];//44100.0
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:16] forKey:AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey];
        [recordSettings setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey];

   // NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/recordTest.caf", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[self copyFile:@"recordTest.caf"]];



    NSError *error = nil;
    audioRecorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSettings error:&error];
    [audioRecorder setDelegate:self];

    if ([audioRecorder prepareToRecord] == YES){
        [audioRecorder record];
        NSLog(@"recording");
    }else {
        int errorCode = CFSwapInt32HostToBig ([error code]);
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ [%4.4s])" , [error localizedDescription], (char*)&errorCode);

    }

}
```

So is it possible to record or monitor sounds from mic input and start recording when sound is above for example 1000 Hz ?

I would also appreciate for literature on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

hope it wil help you [Download the link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SpeakHere/Introduction/Intro.html) l

Comment: I have this as example, but it's hard to read. i would like more simple example